# How to fit a Latex forest tree to A3 paper:

Tags: latex

I'm trying to fit a tree in A3 but no clue how to do so. Any one can help me?
I've tried box,change document class, but no sucess.

I've built my latex:

```
\documentclass[a3paper, landscape]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\forestset{%
  dir tree switch forking/.style args={at #1}{%
    for tree={
      font=\sffamily,
      fit=rectangle,
    },
    where level=#1{
      for tree={
        folder,
        grow'=0,
      },
      delay={
        child anchor=north,
        !u.parent anchor=south,
        edge path'={(!u.parent anchor) -- ++(0,-\forestoption{fork sep}) -| (.child anchor)}
      },
    }{
      if={>On<{level}{#1}}{
        forked edge,
        parent anchor=children,
        child anchor=parent,
      }{},
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      for tree={
        if content={}{
          coordinate,
          no edge,
          before packing={!u.l sep'=0pt},
          before computing xy={s/.option=!u.min x}
        }{
          content/.wrap value={\strut ##1},
        },
      },
      for nodewalk={filter={tree}{>On<{level}{#1}}}{align to centre},
    },
  },
  align to centre/.style={
    if={>Ow+P{n children}{isodd(#1)}}{
      for nodewalk/.process={Ow+nw{!r.n children}{(#1+1)/2}{{fake=r,n=#1}{calign with current edge}}},
    }{
      calign=edge midpoint,
    },
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{adjustbox}{\textwidth}
\begin{forest}
  method/.style={%
    thick,
    edge+={-Latex},
  },
  dir tree switch forking=at 2,
  for tree={
    draw,
    align=center,
    thin,
    %minimum height=20cm,
    text=white,% white text
    top color=blue!90!black,
    bottom color=blue!60!black,
    l sep=5cm,
    s sep=2mm,
  },
  [\LARGE{Secretary} \\ \Large{Name},font=\fontsize{100}{0}% override bold default for second line
    [ \LARGE{Social Communication Advisory} \\ \Large{Name}]
    [ \LARGE{Ombudsman} \\ \Large{Name}]
    [ \LARGE{Administrative Technical Advisory} \\ \Large{Name}]
    [\LARGE{Undersecretary of Housing} \\ \Large{Name}
        [\LARGE{acronym} \\ \Large{Name}
            [\large{acronym I}\\ \Large{Name}]
            [\large{acronym II}\\ \Large{Name}]
            [\large{acronym III}\\ \Large{Name}]
            
        ]
        [\LARGE{acronym} \\ \Large{Name}
            [\large{Budget Management}\\ \Large{Name}]
            [\large{Studies Managements}\\ \Large{Name}]
            [\large{Project Management}\\ \Large{Name}]
        ]
        [\LARGE{acronym} \\ \Large{Name}
            [\large{Housing Management} \\ \Large{Name}
                [\large{Demand Administration Sub-Management}\\ \Large{Name}]
                [\large{Housing Supply Sub-Management}\\ \Large{Name}]
            ]
            [\large{Housing Monitoring Management} \\ \Large{Name}]
            [\large{Housing Requalification Management}\\ \Large{Name}]
        ]
        [\LARGE{acronym} \\ \Large{Name}
            [\large{Resettlement Actions Management}\\ \Large{Name}]
            [\large{Technical-Social Management}\\ \Large{Name}]
        ]
            [\LARGE{acronym} \\ \Large{Name}]
    ]
    [ \LARGE{Chief of Staff} \\ \Large{Name}]
    [ \LARGE{Monitoring of Plans, Programs and Projects} \\ \Large{Name}]
    [\LARGE{Secretariat for Management} \\ \Large{Name}
        [\LARGE{acronym} \\ \Large{Name}]
        [\LARGE{acronym} \\ \Large{Name}
            [\large{Management of Administrative Communications}\\ \Large{Name}]
            [\large{Management of Contracts, Agreements and Bids}\\ \Large{Name}]
        ]
        [\LARGE{acronym} \\ \Large{Name}]
        [\LARGE{acronym} \\ \Large{Name}]
        [\LARGE{Archival Center} \\ \Large{Name}]
    ]
    [\LARGE{Secretariat for Regularization} \\ \Large{Name}
        [\LARGE{acronym} \\ \Large{Name}
            [\large{Urban and Land Regularization Management}\\ \Large{Name}
                [\large{Sub-Management for Urban Regularization}\\ \Large{Name}]
                [\large{Sub-management of Land Regularization}\\ \Large{Name}]
            ]
            [\large{Management of Regularization of Allotments}\\ \Large{Name}]
        ]
        [\LARGE{acronym} \\ \Large{Name}]
    ]    
  ]

\end{forest}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

I have to import it to some graphic software and edit it.

If I could just make it fit in A3 it would save a lot of time. Any one has some tips or sugestions?

I would love a breaf explanation of the solution.
Thanks in advance.

PS> It compiles in overleaf site. But If you know how to make a tree in latex in any other way, I`m glad to learn new stuff, just need it to be similar in structure and fit in A3paper.
[image: My result so far]

Comment: Can you make a compilable [mre]? I get errors with your code...

Comment: I compiled on overleaf, where did you run yours?

Comment: just because overleaf hides errors from you does not mean it compiles there

Comment: I Just added the image to prove. If you want me to do something, I think you should explain better.
I`m not a latex expert, so to me if it draws, compiled (with minor errors, but It did). Should I do something?

Comment: Is LaTeX a requirement?  This seems like a simple problem to solve with Plant UML: https://plantuml.com/

Comment: @HildermesJoséMedeirosFilho You should never ignore error messages. After an error latex only recovers enough to syntax check the rest of the document and does not necessarily produce a sensible output. You should fix all errors before even worrying about the paper format.